# Recursive reheapDown

Tags: c++

I came across this pseudo-code while attempting to find how to recursivly implement reheapDown, but I'm baffled by the `lastUsed` variable in this instance.

```
ReheapDown(node)
begin
   leftChild ← node * 2 + 1
   rightChild ← node * 2 + 2
   if leftChild <= lastUsed
       largest ← leftChild
       if rightChild <= lastUsed AND array[largest] < array[rightChild]
           largest ← rightChild
       end-if
       if array[node] < array[largest]
           Swap(array[node], array[largest])
           ReheapDown(largest)
       end-if
   end-if
end
```

the function only takes one argument(the node in this case), yet uses `lastUsed` which is neither declared nor set at anytime during the function. Could someone explain how this is implemented with the lastUsed? I can figure out everything else:

```
void binaryHeap::reheapDown(int hole)
{
  int leftChild = hole * 2 + 1;
  int rightChild = hole * 2 + 2;
  if(leftChild <= /* ??? */){
    int largest = leftChild;
    if(rightChild <= /* ??? */ && jobHeap[largest] < jobHeap[rightChild])
      largest = rightChild;
    if(jobHeap[hole] < jobHeap[largest]){
      jobElement tmp = jobHeap[hole];
      jobHeap[hole] = jobHeap[largest];
      jobHeap[largest] = tmp;
      reheapDown(largest);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would the caller know lastUsed? It seems like something the binaryHeap would keep to itself, i.e. as a private member.

Comment: You shouldn't just copy the code, translating it superficially to match C++ syntax but rather understand what it does! Clearly, `lastUsed` is just an indicator for the size of the heap (the last used cell in the array). You'll need to find this information from suitable context, e.g., from your object or pass it into the function.